# Hive array with sruct

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Can you please let me know how to create the data for the below dml.

```
create external table doc_sample(id int,topic array<struct<course:string,score:array<struct<sem:string,marks:int>>>>)
ROW FORMAT delimited
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
map keys terminated by ':'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
location '/user/cloudera/data/isaac';

1|'english2':'sem1':80

hive>  select * from doc_sample;
```

OK

```
1       [{"course":"'english2'","score":[{"sem":"'sem1'","marks":null}]}]
```

Time taken: 0.095 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry your question is not fully clear.
1. Do you need to know the formatting of the input file for the DDL which you posted ?
2. Do you need to know how to create the table to achieve the output you have shown in the SELECT query ?

i assumed #2 for my below response. Hope it helps.
to edit a file with nested complex hive data types it is very troublesome. Refer hive guide section on "Collection Data Types" which explains default delimiters ^A, ^B etc and further tells how the next in line ^D and so on are used for nested data types. Anyways it is difficult to edit files manually with Ctrl characters.
The better approach is to have JSON format input file and use the jsonserde for the hive table. Here is how i created the sample,

`create table doc_sample_json
    (id int,
    topic array<struct<course:string,score:array<struct<sem:string,marks:bigint>>>>
    ) 
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'`

> json.txt input data
>
> {"id":1,"topic":[{"course":"english1","score":[{"sem":"sem1","marks":5}]},{"course":"english1","score":[{"sem":"sem1","marks":10},{"sem":"sem2","marks":15}]}]}
>
> LOAD data local inpath '/user/docs/json.txt'  overwrite into table doc_sample_json;

`hive> select * from doc_sample_json;
    OK
1   [{"course":"english1","score":[{"sem":"sem1","marks":5}]},{"course":"english1","score":[{"sem":"sem1","marks":10},{"sem":"sem2","marks":15}]}]`

Comment: Hello Kunal,My apology for the pain. I am using Cloudera VM. How can I use the Json jsonserde.JsonSerDe'. Can you please bit explain me regarding same.FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot validate serde: org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe

Comment: This is a custom serde jar and you need to make it available to your hive. There are few more of such serdes to do the same task. Sorry I have not used the Cloudera VM but to use any custom serde the basic steps remain same. Download the serde jar which fits your platform from online sites like Google code , github , etc. Add jar xyz.serde.jsonserde.jar to your hive installation or everytime you run hive cli. Stepswise info for CDH specific should also be available online if you just search for "adding custom serde jars to cloudera".